# Role provider not working with SQL Server Enterprise

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am getting the following error,

> The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.

from the below line of code in my razor view(MVC5)

```
@if(Roles.IsUserInRole("User"){}
```

I have upgraded my database sql server from Express 2012 to Enterprise 2012 edition . After that I got above error. Since my application is EF code-first, database is created automatically but role provider doesn't seem to be working.

```
<add name="Foo" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Foo_db;User ID=sa;Password=******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Show us the **connection string**! The error says that you're using `User Instance=....` in your connection, which is a feature that works in **Express** ONLY.

Comment: User instance only supports in express edition, so i haven't used user instance. But i can able to create db from code first,successfully. The only thing is role based operations throwing the error above mentioned.

Comment: I have upgraded my sql server edition from express to enterprise. And i left the instance name as EXPRESS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread.  It should help.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1939748.aspx

*I have tested this, User.IsInRole is now working for me.  Make sure you have this in your Startup class*

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to put the application name in your web config?

```
  <roleManager enabled="true">
   <providers>
      <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"       
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" 
             applicationName="DONT FORGET THIS PART" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: what exact name has to go there?